# Show that Wronskian is time independent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Let $q:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are the solutions to ODE: $\ddot{x}=q(t)x$ on $(a,b)$, show that Wronskian determinate
$$ \begin{vmatrix} x_1(t)
 & x_2(t)\\ 
 \dot{x_1}(t)& \dot{x_2}(t)
\end{vmatrix} $$

is time independent on $(a,b)$.

I am not sure how to start this problem at all and I would appreciate any help.

**Edit 1:**

**Edit 2:**

**Edit 3:** Edits 1 and 2 have been summarised in the answer provided down.

Comment: Consider $\frac{d}{dt} W(t)$ and see what you get

Comment: So I did that, I got: $\dot{x_1}(t) \dot{x_2}(t)+x_1(t) \ddot{x_2}(t)-  \ddot{x_1}(t)x_1(t)- \dot{x_1}(t) \dot{x_2}(t)$. Or basically we get two determinants, it's too much to write in the comments. Am I looking for the $Tr(A)$ or there is something else?

Comment: Keep going. Do you see what you can do to simplify that expression?

Comment: @runway44 Thank you! So I simplified to the best of my knowledge, and I am only left with: $x_1(t) \ddot{x_2}(t)-  \ddot{x_1}(t)x_1(t)$, I am still unsure how this would imply time independence?

Comment: Keep going. Now use the fact $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions to $\ddot{x}=qx$.

Comment: @runway44 I am sorry, but I am really not sure how to proceed further. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ does that mean that $x(t) = c_1x_1(t)+c_2x_2(t)$ and I should somehow use that or? **Edit 1:** Could we say that sincev$ \dot{x}$ term is missing from the equation that $\dot{W}$ has to be equal zero or?

Comment: The fact $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions to $\ddot{x}=qx$ tells you you can replace $\ddot{x}_1$ and $\ddot{x}_2$ with $qx_1$ and $qx_2$. What happens to your expression when you do that?

Comment: @runway44 Oh I totally missed that, in that case, they would cancel each other once we calculate the determinate and that would be enough to imply independence. Thank you!

Comment: You should answer your own question!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the summary of the hints and help from the comments and my calculation:

First, we calculate the derivative of the Wronskian:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\begin{vmatrix} x_1(t)
 & x_2(t)\\ 
 \dot{x_1}(t)& \dot{x_2}(t)
\end{vmatrix} = \dot{x_1}(t) \dot{x_2}(t)+x_1(t) \ddot{x_2}(t)-  \ddot{x_1}(t)x_1(t)- \dot{x_1}(t) \dot{x_2}(t)
$$

$$ = \begin{vmatrix} x_1(t)
 & x_2(t)\\ 
 \ddot{x_1}(t)& \ddot{x_2}(t)
\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} \dot{x_1}(t)
 & \dot{x_2}(t)\\ 
 \dot{x_1}(t)& \dot{x_2}(t)
\end{vmatrix}$$

but since the second determinate is equal to zero we are left with

$$ = \begin{vmatrix} x_1(t)
 & x_2(t)\\ 
 \ddot{x_1}(t)& \ddot{x_2}(t)
\end{vmatrix}$$

Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the solutions of $\ddot{x}=q(t)x$ then we can substitute them in our determinante:

$$ = \begin{vmatrix} x_1(t)
 & x_2(t)\\ 
 q(t)x_1 & q(t)x_2
\end{vmatrix} = x_1q(t)x_2(t)-x_2q(t)x_1 = 0 \Rightarrow \dot{W}=0$$

Since $\dot{W}=0$, it follows that it´s time-independent.