# Verify that $x_1$ is a solution of Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

[Following from this problem on time independence of Wronskian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4562471/show-that-wronskian-is-time-independent)

Let $q:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are the solutions to ODE: $\ddot{x}=q(t)x$ on $(a,b)$, we know that Wronskian determinate
$$ \begin{vmatrix} x_1(t)
 & x_2(t)\\ 
 \dot{x_1}(t)& \dot{x_2}(t)
\end{vmatrix} $$

is time independent on $(a,b)$, since $\dot{W}=0$ in this case. If we assume that $$q(t)= \frac{3-2\sin(t) \cos(t)}{1+2\sin(t)\cos(t)}$$ and $a=0<b=\frac{\pi}{2}$, I have to verify that $$x_1(t) = \frac{1}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)}$$

is a solution to the ODE.

My initial try was to calculate the second derivative of $x_1$ and multiply it with the $q(t)$ but that got quite messy, is there another more elegant way to verify it?

Answer (score 1):

Start with $x=v^{-1}$. Then $\dot x=-v^{-2}\dot v$ and
$$
\ddot x=-v^{-2}\ddot v+2v^{-3}\dot v^2=\frac qv
$$
On the other hand, $\ddot v=-v$ and so you need to test if
$$
1+2v^{-2}\dot v^2=q
$$
Now apply
$$
(\sin t\pm\cos t)^2=1\pm2\cos t\sin t
$$

Comment: Oh thank you, I have actually managed to deal with the second derivative and come to the same conclusion. Using just the presented information and calculations done, would it be possible to find explicit $x_2$ such that is linearly independent?

Comment: You know $x_1\dot x_2-\dot x_1x_2=1$, which is first-order linear for $x_2$. Insert to get $\dot x_2+2v^{-1}\dot v=v$, $(\frac{d}{dt}(v^2x_2)=v^3$, the integral of the right side could be a little long, but $(s+c)^3=s(1-c^2)+3s^2c+3sc^2+c(1-s^2)=s+c+2s^2c+2sc^2$, which is now term-wise directly integrable.

Comment: Thanks, the only question I have is, why Wronskian in your case is equal to 1?

Comment: You know that it is a constant, you can change the constant with a constant factor to one basis solution, so taking 1 is as good as any other non-zero value.